# grouping pandas dataframe by two columns (or more)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
mydf = pandas.DataFrame({"cat": ["first", "first", "first", "second", "second", "third"], "class": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C"], "name": ["a1", "a2", "a3", "b1", "b2", "c1"], "val": [1,5,1,1,2,10]})
```

I want to create a dataframe that makes summary statistics about the `val` column of items with the same `class` id. For this I use `groupby` as follows:

```
mydf.groupby("class").val.sum()
```

that's the correct behavior, but I'd like to retain the `cat` column information in the resulting df. can that be done? do I have to `merge/join` that info in later? I tried:

```
mydf.groupby(["cat", "class"]).val.sum()
```

but this uses hierarchical indexing. I'd like to have a plain dataframe back that just has the `cat` value for each group, where the group by is `class`. The output should be a dataframe (not series) with the values of cat and class, where the `val` entries are summed over each entry that has the same `class`:

```
cat     class    val
first   A         7
second  B         3
third   C        10
```

is this possible?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want your output to be?

Comment: @BrenBarn: just added it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `reset_index`

```
In [9]: mydf.groupby(['cat', "class"]).val.sum().reset_index()
Out[9]: 
      cat class  val
0   first     A    7
1  second     B    3
2   third     C   10
```

### EDIT

set level=1 if you want to set `cat` as index

```
In [10]: mydf.groupby(['cat', "class"]).val.sum().reset_index(level=1)
Out[10]: 
       class  val
cat              
first      A    7
second     B    3
third      C   10
```

You can also set `as_index=False` to get the same output

```
In [29]: mydf.groupby(['cat', "class"], as_index=False).val.sum()
Out[29]: 
      cat class  val
0   first     A    7
1  second     B    3
2   third     C   10
```

Comment: Might want to use `reset_index(level=1)`, since in the sample output it looks like he does want `cat` as the index (just not `cat` *and* class).  This data is somewhat strange as it seems `cat` and `class` redundantly provide the same information.

Comment: Beautiful I always forget this helpful function!

Comment: as_index=False is another way to get round the reset_index bit.