# groupby / aggregate dataframe with non-numeric types

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following situation

```
date_range = pd.date_range('20180101', '20180105')
date_list = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(date, 2) for date in date_range))
num_list = np.random.randint(1,100,size=(10))
date2 = ['2018-12-31']*10

df = pd.DataFrame({'date1':date_list,'numbers':num_list,'date2':date2})
```

displaying this dataframe gives

```
      date1        date2    numbers
0   2018-01-01  2018-12-31  38
1   2018-01-01  2018-12-31  2
2   2018-01-02  2018-12-31  8
3   2018-01-02  2018-12-31  51
4   2018-01-03  2018-12-31  16
5   2018-01-03  2018-12-31  22
6   2018-01-04  2018-12-31  43
7   2018-01-04  2018-12-31  76
8   2018-01-05  2018-12-31  47
9   2018-01-05  2018-12-31  50
```

i would like to obtain a new dataframe which is a) grouped by date1, b) sums up the values for each date1 in the numbers column, and c) keeps the date2 value (which we can assume would be the same for each date1 or, in this case, the same for the entire dataframe

i can do the following to achieve a+b, but if i try to include something like 'date2':'mean' in the aggregation dictionary it will not work and return DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

```
df.groupby(['date1'],as_index=False).agg({'numbers':'sum'})
```

any advice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [grouping pandas dataframe by two columns (or more)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21247992/grouping-pandas-dataframe-by-two-columns-or-more)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you need if `date2` is same for each group:

```
df.groupby(['date1', 'date2'],as_index=False).agg({'numbers':'sum'})
```

Or need aggregate by [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df.groupby(['date1'],as_index=False).agg({'numbers':'sum','date2':'first'})
```

But if need `mean` of `datetime` it is a bit complicated:

```
df['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date2'])
f = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x.values.astype(np.int64).mean())
df1 = df.groupby(['date1'],as_index=False).agg({'numbers':'sum','date2':f})
print (df1)
       date1  numbers      date2
0 2018-01-01      159 2018-12-31
1 2018-01-02      104 2018-12-31
2 2018-01-03       75 2018-12-31
3 2018-01-04       98 2018-12-31
4 2018-01-05      184 2018-12-31
```

Comment: This answer is really clever!

Answer (score 0):

Because of c):

> keeps the date2 value (which we can assume would be the same for each date1 or, in this case, the same for the entire dataframe

... you can add it to the group by clause:

```
df.groupby(['date1', 'date2'],as_index=False).agg({'numbers':'sum'})
```

... giving:

```
       date1       date2  numbers
0 2018-01-01  2018-12-31       35
1 2018-01-02  2018-12-31       52
2 2018-01-03  2018-12-31      104
3 2018-01-04  2018-12-31       96
4 2018-01-05  2018-12-31      151
```